# Adicionar Facebook sdk 3.20.0 no Android Studio 0.9.2

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

Estou com problema na hora de adicionar o sdk do facebook no Androido Studio 0.9.2.

Sempre me retorna a seguinte messagens

```
Failed to find: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2
```

Alguma solução?

Importei o modulo para dentro do meu projeto.

Minha configuração do arquivo build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

minSdkVersion    10
targetSdkVersion 21
```

Só fiz essa modifição do build.gradle original do facebook.

Comment: Você importou o facebookSDK como módulo do seu projeto? Pode postar o build.gradle inteiro por favor?

Answer (score 2):

tente essa solução:

- Baixe o Facebook SDK(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)
- Descompacte o arquivo facebook-android-sdk-3.20.0
- No Android Studio realize a seguinte operação: File menu->Import Module
- Escolha “facebook” dentro da pasta descompactada.
- Vá para o diretório  facebook/build.grade  altere o conteúdo para este:

  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  ```
  project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

  dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
      compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
  }

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 19
      buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

      defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 10
          targetSdkVersion 19
      }

      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }

      sourceSets {
          main {
              manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
              java.srcDirs = ['src']
              res.srcDirs = ['res']
          }
      }
  }

  apply plugin: 'maven'
  apply plugin: 'signing'

  def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
  def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
  def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

  task setVersion {
      // The version will be derived from source
      project.version = null
      def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
      sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
          def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
          if (matcher.matches()) {
            project.version = matcher[0][1]
            return
          }
      }
      if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
        throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
      }
  }

  uploadArchives {
      repositories.mavenDeployer {
          beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

          repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
              authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
          }

          snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
              authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
          }

          pom.project {
              name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
              artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
              packaging 'aar'
              description 'Facebook Android SDK'
              url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

              scm {
                  connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                  developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                  url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
              }

              licenses {
                  license {
                      name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                      url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                      distribution 'repo'
                  }
              }

              developers {
                  developer {
                      id 'facebook'
                      name 'Facebook'
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

  signing {
      required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
      sign configurations.archives
  }

  task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
      source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
      classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
  }

  task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
      classifier = 'javadoc'
      from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
  }

  task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
      classifier = 'sources'
      from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
  }

  artifacts {
      archives androidSourcesJar
      archives androidJavadocsJar
  }

  afterEvaluate {
      androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
  }
  ```
- Clique em seu projeto e pressione F4 , vá para tab'dependencies', clique em '+', ' module dependency' e selecione seu projeto importado do Facebook.
- Agora é só dar um Resync e um rebuild